# lxml get the all the html of an xpath selected element

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

So I have a given piece of HTML and I want to select a part of it using `xpath` and `lxml`

```
from lxml import etree  

example_html = '''
    <div>
     <span>
       <p>abc</p>
       <p>def</p>
     </span>
    </div>
'''

htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(example_html, htmlparser)

el = tree.xpath('//div')
```

`el` now is obviously this `[<Element div at 0x7f61154c3f88>]` what I want to do is a `el[0].get_html()` to get:

```
 <span>
   <p>abc</p>
   <p>def</p>
 </span>
```

Is this possible? And if not with lxml is there another library?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with BeautifulSoup,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example_html = '''
    <div>
     <span>
       <p>abc</p>
       <p>def</p>
     </span>
    </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(example_html)
print(soup.span)


<span>
       <p>abc</p>
       <p>def</p>
</span>
```

Comment: yeah I actually want to put the output into BeautifulSoup to get the text, but I find `xpath` very powerful to "select" parts of very complex html documents